# why should I have to zoom out to see the annotation in mapview in iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm implementing a map view specific location with longitude and latitude.like below.

```
 self.hotelmapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.hotelmapView.showsBuildings = YES;


    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    //[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; --> no need to add this for real devices.else should add this.

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPint = [MKPointAnnotation new];
    annotationPint.title = @"anuradh hotel name";
    annotationPint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.585300, -0.1257480);


    notationarray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [notationarray addObject:annotationPint];
```

**NOTE : This works fine in simulator.when I test with the device, I have to zoom out to see the map(pin showing with square table,not showing the map)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will occur on IOS8.3 and later version  both sim and device (may be its a bug ). the system  Maps App running (it shows empty grid as well) for a minute till it downloaded maps. there after MKMapView started rendering as normal .

Comment: I kept more than enough time.but didn't show the map. any solution for this?

Comment: I also face the same issues on my work time, alternate way I changed the map type as standard and then it shows in iphone 5 family ony

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.if you get to know any solution, please kind enough to make me aware.it will help to others also.